# After modifying the file name on my own app,there is no relevant activity records

Tags: windows, workflow, record

After modifying the file name on my own app, I checked the activity records on ACC, but there were no relevant records, as shown in the following figure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czzZE.png)

But if I make the same modifications on ACC, there is a record.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVUbK.png)

How can I do the same on my app？ What I mean is that when I rename a file on my app, I can automatically generate a record of file activity on ACC.

I have tried to rename the file , Although I successfully renamed the file, I don't know how to set the meta section. Is it correct to set the meta section so that the activity record of the file can be automatically displayed on Acc?

```
          // changeProperties
            public static function changeProperties($AutodeskToken, $url, $project_id, $item_id, $newName) 
            {

                //$url = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/$project_id/versions?copyFrom=$version_id";

                $head = [
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $AutodeskToken,
                    'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json'
                ];
        
                $body = [
                  'jsonapi' => [
                    'version' => '1.0',
                  ],
                  'data' => [
                    'type' => 'versions',
                    'attributes' => [
                          'name' => $newName,
                          'displayName' => $newName,
                          "extension" => [
                            "version" => "1.0"
                          ]
                        ],
                    'relationships' => [
                         'item' => [
                           'data' => [
                              'type' => 'items',
                              'id' => $item_id,
                           ],
                         ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    // 'meta' => [
                    //     'workflow' => 'mocheng_00001', 
                    //     'workflowAttribute' => [
                    //        'myfoo' => 33,
                    //        'projectId' => str_replace("b", "a", $project_id, 1),
                    //        'myobject' => [
                    //          'nested' => true,
                    //        ],
                    //     ],
                    // ],
                 ];
                $body = json_encode($body);
        
                $result = self::curlsent($url, $body, $head, 'post');
                return $result;
            }
```